# Как напечатать содержимое QTableWidget

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

Имеется заполненая таблица QTableWidget можно ли её как то пустить на печать средствами Qt 5?

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/24104558/qtablewidget-print-table-on-paper

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Это возможно при помощи классов `QPrint`,  `QPrintDialog` и `QPainter`.

Сначала создайте ваш принтер, минимальный код:

```
QPrinter printer;
QPrintDialog dialog(&printer, this);
```

Для распечатки вашей таблицы воспользуйтесь классом `QPainter`:

```
if (dialog.exec() == QDialog::Accepted) {
    QPainter painter(&printer);
    tableWidget->render(&painter);
}
```

В случае, если у вас возникнут проблемы с масштабом, надо будет про-масштабировать `painter` (при помощи таких комманд как `painter.scale()` и `painter.translate()`).

Более подробные примеры можно найти: http://doc.qt.io/qt-5/qtprintsupport-index.html